# Alternative to VLC VLM for Camera Monitoring

Tags: vlc-media-player, recording, software-rec, network-camera

We've been using VLC's VLM but it's just too painful to deal with any more with no relief in sight, so I'm looking for a solution that can:

- Take multiple feeds from IP cameras and captures cards and;

  - Encode original streams using any standard codec (lossless or close to lossless) with user definable timestamp embedded into video.
  - Can take advantage of multiple cores.
  - [Can automatically split output files after reaching certain file size.](http://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/561)
- Display all streams in a [mosaic](http://wiki.videolan.org/Mosaic) for the operator.
- Actually has documentation...
- Doesn't cause ViewCast Osprey cards to crash the whole system every few hours...

The emphasis is on quality and many solutions (Eg: security oriented) have been inadequate which is why we went with VLC in the first place. Although we'd prefer software that can run on the machine doing the capturing, if we had to go headless and have software to display the mosaic for operator elsewhere then that would work too.

Comment: Do you just need a tool that does exactly what you describe, or would you be happy with a CCTV surveillance suite that *also* does the things you mention? If so, take a look at Zoneminder (I'd have to verify that it can really re-encode output strems, but otherwise, you should be fine).

Comment: We looked at Zoneminder a while back last review, it didn't support our cards properly and we couldn't get it to parse the camera streams. Doesn't have to do those things exactly, it's a just a minimum, although a very minimalist and clean interface is desirable.